# In call volume (earpiece) too loud on Nexus 4 (ubuntu touch)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

I'm running ubuntu touch (stable, mako: #24) on my Nexus 4. During calls the volume of the earpiece is much too loud (minimum setting).
The volume buttons just change the volume from loud to very loud.

Is there a way to change the max/min settings?

[edit: ]
Tried to play around with alsamixer/ amixer. Can anybody tell me which entry corresponds to the earpiece?